# ListView DropDownList Edit ListView

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I have created a ListView that has editing enabled, the wizard generated the table with the use of textboxes but i require the use of dropdown lists for some options.

I have created the dropdown list

```
 <asp:DropDownList ID="ActionStatusTextBox" runat="server">
                    <asp:ListItem Value="Ongoing">Ongoing</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="Open">Open</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="Closed">Closed</asp:ListItem>
 </asp:DropDownList>
```

The drop down list generates successfully but doesn't submit and enter itself in the databse.

```
<%# Bind("ActionStatus") %>'
```

The above snippet needs to used somewhere in order to bind the data but which parameter does it need attaching to to pass the data?

I've tried everything and its giving me a right headache!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Did you try:

```
<asp:DropDownList .. SelectedValue='<%# Bind("ActionStatus") %>' />
```

The SelectedValue property doesn't appear, but I believe you can set it this way.

HTH.

Answer (score 0):

What are you attempting to insert into the database? You shouldn't need to bind anything if you add your listitems manually.  You could just

```
string value = ActionStatusTextBox.SelectedValue;
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.  Check out this thread: [Why is employee_id not being inserted into database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5737508/why-is-employee-id-not-being-inserted-into-database)

The key was in adding a function:

```
Protected Sub AbsentListView_ItemInserting(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListViewInsertEventArgs) Handles AbsentListView.ItemInserting
    e.Values("employee_id") = DirectCast(AbsentListView.InsertItem.FindControl("ExcusedAbsences_employee_idDropDownList2"), DropDownList).SelectedValue
End Sub
```

Which basically set the value of the dropdown when it needed it, and once i did this, the value was going into the database.

Answer (score 0):

```
protected void ContactsListView_ItemDataBound(object sender, ListViewItemEventArgs e)
{

  //Verify there is an item being edited.
  if (ContactsListView.EditIndex >= 0)
  {

    //Get the item object.
    ListViewDataItem dataItem = (ListViewDataItem)e.Item;

    // Check for an item in edit mode.
    if (dataItem.DisplayIndex == ContactsListView.EditIndex)
    {

      // Preselect the DropDownList control with the Title value
      // for the current item.

      // Retrieve the underlying data item. In this example
      // the underlying data item is a DataRowView object.        
      DataRowView rowView = (DataRowView)dataItem.DataItem;

      // Retrieve the Title value for the current item. 
      String title = rowView["Title"].ToString();

      // Retrieve the DropDownList control from the current row. 
      DropDownList list = (DropDownList)dataItem.FindControl("TitlesList");

      // Find the ListItem object in the DropDownList control with the 
      // title value and select the item.
      ListItem item = list.Items.FindByText(title);
      list.SelectedIndex = list.Items.IndexOf(item);

    }
  }
}
```