# Why is employee_id not being inserted into database

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2005, listview

```
    <asp:TabPanel ID="AbsentTabPanel" runat="server" HeaderText="Excused Absences">
        <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:ListView ID="AbsentListView" runat="server" InsertItemPosition="LastItem"
                DataSourceID="AbsentSqlDataSource" DataKeyNames="">

            <InsertItemTemplate>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="ExcusedAbsences_employee_idDropDownList2" runat="server">
                            <asp:ListItem Text="John Smith" Value="1" />
                            <asp:ListItem Text="Indiana Jones" Value="2" />
                        </asp:DropDownList> 

                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <!-- start date -->
                        <asp:TextBox ID="start_dt_codeTextBox" runat="server" Columns="6" Text='<%#Bind("start_dt")%>' />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <!-- end date -->
                        <asp:TextBox ID="end_dt_codeTextBox" runat="server" Columns="6" Text='<%#Bind("end_dt")%>' />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Button runat="server" CommandName="Insert" Text="insert" />
                        <asp:Button runat="server" CommandName="Clear" Text="clear" />
                    </td>
                </tr>                    
            </InsertItemTemplate>
```

...

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="AbsentSqlDataSource" runat="server"
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:Rotations3ConnectionString %>"
    SelectCommand="SELECT employee_id, start_dt, end_dt
                     FROM Excused_Absences
                    WHERE fy = @fy AND pgy = @pgy"

    UpdateCommand="UPDATE Excused_Absences
                      SET start_dt = @start_dt, end_dt = @end_dt, employee_id = @employee_id
                    WHERE absence_nbr = @absence_nbr"

    InsertCommand="INSERT INTO Excused_Absences (fy, pgy, employee_id, start_dt, end_dt)
                        VALUES (@fy, @pgy, @employee_id, @start_dt, @end_dt)"

    OldValuesParameterFormatString="old_{0}">

    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:ControlParameter Name="fy" Type="Int32" ControlID="fyTextBox" PropertyName="Text" />
        <asp:ControlParameter Name="pgy" Type="Int32" ControlID="pgyTextBox" PropertyName="Text" />
    </SelectParameters>

    <InsertParameters>
        <asp:ControlParameter Name="fy" Type="Int32" ControlID="fyTextBox" PropertyName="Text" />
        <asp:ControlParameter Name="pgy" Type="Int32" ControlID="pgyTextBox" PropertyName="Text" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="employee_id" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="start_dt" Type="DateTime" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="end_dt" Type="DateTime" />
    </InsertParameters>
```

For some reason when I insert John Smith or Indiana Jones, the employee_id is not inserted into the database, I get a NULL value.  What am I missing?

Comment: Is employee_id supposed to be a string? Normally an id is an int or bigint.

Comment: Also your UpdateCommand has no parameters defined in <UpdateParameters>

Comment: Yes, i have it setup in the DB as a char(9), because it's 9 digits, sometimes all 0's.  like 000000000.

Comment: Would the <UpdateParameters> effect the way the Insert works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it!  long time programmer, but novice to asp.net so I'm not sure of the reason, but just poking around other code that did the same thing i wanted, I was able to write this function:

```
Protected Sub AbsentListView_ItemInserting(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListViewInsertEventArgs) Handles AbsentListView.ItemInserting
    e.Values("employee_id") = DirectCast(AbsentListView.InsertItem.FindControl("ExcusedAbsences_employee_idDropDownList2"), DropDownList).SelectedValue
End Sub
```

I couldn't find any call to this function, but apparnetly it gets called automatically with every insert of my "AbsentlistView" item.

This function somehow tells the SQL command what the value should be for the drop down, and therefore when the SQL command goes, it has the correct value in the employee_id field.

Thanks all for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Make the employee_id parameter a ControlParameter like the pgy parameter.  The controlID should be the DropDownlist ID.

```
<asp:ControlParameter Name="pgy" Type="Int32" ControlID="pgyTextBox" PropertyName="Text" />
<asp:Parameter Name="employee_id" Type="String" />
```

Or, you could manually set the parameter to a value.

Comment: Man, i was really hoping that would be my answer, but it causes this error:  "Could not find control 'ExcusedAbsences_employee_idDropDownList2' in ControlParameter 'employee_id'."   Even though i've double checked and the id is correct.

I changed it to this:
     <asp:ControlParameter Name="employee_id" Type="String" ControlID="ExcusedAbsences_employee_idDropDownList2"/>

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to bind the `ExcusedAbsences_employee_idDropDownList2` `SelectedValue` property to the `employee_ID` field.

Comment: When i use this: SelectedValue='<%#Bind("employee_id")%>' -  I get this error message: "Databinding methods such as Eval(), XPath(), and Bind() can only be used in the context of a databound control."

Comment: Read about it: http://aspadvice.com/blogs/joteke/archive/2008/08/24/Is-_2200_Databinding-methods-such-as-Eval_280029002C00_-XPath_280029002C00_-and-Bind_28002900_-can-only-be-used-in-the-context-of-a-databound-control_2E002200_-causing-you-grief_3F00_.aspx